# AngularJS with Google Maps Radius

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create an app using AngularJS that takes a user's location (from their mobile) and creates a radius that increases in size over time. Here is what I have so far: http://alainwebdesign.ca/doglocate/example/issue-1068-circle-events-doubled.html.

The app works for the most part, but the problem is that when you move/drag the map, the radius center changes which is not what I want. I want the center of the radius to be lock in at the specified location.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/example.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="../website_libs/dev_deps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger/0.0.1/dist/index.js"></script><script src="../dist/angular-google-maps_dev_mapped.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/controllers/issue-1068-circle-events-doubled.js"></script>
    <title>Dog Locate</title>
</head>

<body>



<div data-ng-controller="MapsCtrl">
    <ui-gmap-google-map 
                        center='map.center'
                        zoom='map.zoom'
                        draggable='map.draggable'
                        dragging='map.dragging'
                        refresh='map.refresh'
                        options='map.options'
                        events='map.events'
                        pan='map.pan'>


        <ui-gmap-circle 
                        center='map.circle.center'
                        radius='map.circle.radius'
                        fill='map.circle.fill'
                        stroke='map.circle.stroke'
                        clickable='map.circle.clickable'
                        draggable='map.circle.draggable'
                        editable='map.circle.editable'
                        visible='map.circle.visible'
                        events='map.circle.events'>

        </ui-gmap-circle>


    </ui-gmap-google-map>


</div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is my Javascript:

```
(function (window, ng) {
    ng.module('app', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
    .controller('MapsCtrl', ['$scope', "uiGmapLogger", "uiGmapGoogleMapApi", "$interval",
      function ($scope, $log, GoogleMapApi, $interval) {
          $log.currentLevel = $log.LEVELS.debug;
          var center = {
              latitude: 49.22,
              longitude: -122.66
          };

          $scope.map = {
              center: center,
              pan: false,
              zoom: 16,
              refresh: false,
              events: {},
              bounds: {}
          };

          $scope.map.circle = {
              id: 1,
              center: center,
              radius: 500,
              stroke: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  weight: 2,
                  opacity: 1
              },

              fill: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  opacity: 0.5
              },
              geodesic: false, // optional: defaults to false
              draggable: false, // optional: defaults to false
              clickable: true, // optional: defaults to true
              editable: false, // optional: defaults to false
              visible: true, // optional: defaults to true
              events: {
                  dblclick: function () {
                      $log.debug("circle dblclick");
                  },
                  radius_changed: function (gObject) {
                      var radius = gObject.getRadius();
                      $log.debug("circle radius radius_changed " + radius);
                  }
              }
          }
          //Increase Radius:
          $interval(function(){
                $scope.map.circle.radius += 30;
          }, 1000);
      } ]);



})(window, angular);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question. I just used Object.freeze(center) after declaring the center variable.